# How to disable Spring Cloud Kubernetes in a Maven build

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, kubernetes, spring-cloud

Running Spring Boot 2.6.6 and Spring Cloud 2021.0.1

I'm attempting to migrate an existing service to Kubernetes so I added a dependency on `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-all`. By default, I have `spring.cloud.kubernetes.enable=false` and use the `kubernetes` profile to enable it. This is intended to allow this service to operate in both Kubernetes and the legacy environment.

My unit-tests complete successfully when building locally but fail in my Bitbucket pipeline with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.NamespaceResolutionFailedException: unresolved namespace
```

I suspect this occurs because Bitbucket Pipelines are deployed in Kubernetes and Spring somehow detects this. I have tried the following to no avail

- Pass `--define SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_ENABLED=false` to Maven on the command line
- Set this as an environment variable e.g., `export SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_ENABLED=false`
- Pass `--define spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled=false` to Maven on the command line

I have also checked StackOverflow for similar issues and investigated the code also without avail. The class that is actually raising the issue is `KubernetesClientConfigUtils`, which should be disabled.

I would appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Cloud checks whether the application is running in a K8s environment before loading the active spring profile configuration and adds `kubernetes` to the active profiles. Previously, in Hoxton SR10, the profile was identified and `bootstrap-<profile>.yml` loaded before checking for Kubernetes. `spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled` was picked up from there if set in the profile configuration or the maven pom properties.

As maven allows setting system properties on the command line, kubernetes detection can be disabled by setting it there:

```
mvn test -Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled=false
```

The surefire maven plugin allows setting system properties for all tests, so it's possible to set `spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled` to be `false` in the surefire plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled>false</spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It is also possible to set the configuration on individual test classes using @Faron's approach to explicitly set the property in any `WebMvcTest` annotated unit test, e.g.:

```
@WebMvcTest(properties = { "spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled=false" })
```

It should also work on other unit test annotation that loads a Spring application context, such as `WebFluxTest`.

Comment: If you want to update your answer to include all the ways to solve this issue (including my solution), I will select your answer over mine and up-vote it. I do not get reputation points for answering my own question. I also recommend moving the last paragraph to the beginning and rephrase it so that it describes what is happening (i.e., no blaming).

Answer (score 1):

After trying a few other approaches, I finally stumbled upon one that works. I added the property to the unit-test context using

```
@WebMvcTest(properties = { "spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled=false" })
```

This should also work for any unit-test annotation that load a Spring application context such as `@WebFluxTest`

Answer (score 1):

after upgrading to spring boot 2.7.x and spring cloud 2021.x I also got the issue:

```bash
NamespaceResolutionFailedException: unresolved namespace
```

The solution for me was to add a `bootstrap.yml` file in the test `resources` folder with the following:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    compatibility-verifier.enabled: false
    kubernetes:
      enabled: false
      reload.enabled: false
      discovery.enabled: false
```

(remove it from the `application.yml` if it was there)

From documentation:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-bootstrap-properties

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues?q=unresolved+namespace